# Resource.Designer.cs is generated with no code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, embedded-resource

I am working with Visual Studio, I want to add English and Spanish Resources but when the Resource.Designer.cs is generated there is no code in it.

My resource folder looks like this:

[image: My resource folder looks like this:]

And the properties that are set to one of my resource files(English) are these:

Resource.en-US.resx properties:

[image: Resource.en-US.resx properties]

Any suggestion?